# Class case exception in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I deployed a web application to weblogic 12c. But I got the error in Oracle weblogic configuration shows as below:

```
**java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl cannot be cast to weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicWebAppBean**
```

I didn't experience the same issue with the older version of weblogic.

Can anybody suggest how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check your descriptors: do they have namespaces defined?

For instance, if you use a weblogic-application.xml descriptor, the root element should be:

```
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application” etc.
```

The older Weblogic (11) was not as strict about this.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have notes this happen only application which we use structs 1.0, I have deployed application which we developed structs 2.0 working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Descriptor error comes only when you use the old or wrong descriptor in the xml files. This issue comes either with weblogic-application.xml or weblogic.xml..

Use the latest weblogic12c descriptor to get away from the issue.